# Match on substring

Tags: mysql

How would I do the following query? I want to match on the entire string minus the last two characters. In python it would be:

```
>>> x='hello'
>>> x[:-2]
'hel'
```

Conceptually, in SQL it would be:

```
select * from main_tmp where vid_country_key[:-2] = '2wh_gQwkMQg'
```

How would I actually do this? And would the above be faster or slower than:

```
select * from main_tmp where vid_country_key LIKE '2wh_gQwkMQg%'
```

Comment: You'd do the latter. You could use a substring function to get all but the last 2 letters, but you'd lose any indexing advantage

Comment: The first would be slower than the second; doing any sort of operation on field values involved in comparison usually negates the advantages of indexes. (I say usually because the optimizer MIGHT convert something like `field + 1 = 2` to `field = 1`, but I highly doubt it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you probably know, the two example queries you provided are not equivalent, but altering the second like so should give the same results as the first, and might keep the potential indexing advantage of the second:

```
SELECT * 
FROM main_tmp 
WHERE vid_country_key LIKE '2wh_gQwkMQg%'
   AND LENGTH(vid_country_key) = LENGTH('2wh_gQwkMQg')+2
;
```

If it doesn't use the index (assuming there is one), you could try changing `AND` to `HAVING`, or look into `USE INDEX`.

Oh, for the record, if you wanted to know the actual syntax for your first example, it would be

```
WHERE LEFT(vid_country_key, GREATEST(LENGTH(vid_country_key)-2, 0)) = '2wh_gQwkMQg'
```

the `GREATEST` is need in case the length of the field is less than 2.